# How does Iron-router determine route priority?

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

Let's say you have the following route definitions:

```
   @route "home1",
      path: "/:homeSlug1
```

and

```
   @route "home2",
      path: "/:homeSlug2
```

and

```
   @route "home3",
      path: "/fixedPath
```

and then go to `localhost:3000/fixedPath` in the browser

how does Iron-Router choose the priority?

It does not appear that the fixedpath route takes precedence over the parameterized route. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `Router.route(...)`, that new route is pushed to the back of an array of possible routes. When a request comes in, IronRouter goes through that array and picks the first one that matches. So the precendence follows directly from the order in which you specify your routes.

A look at the [source](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/lib/router.js#L141) makes it clear:

```js
 Router.prototype.route = function (path, fn, opts) {
   ...
   var route = new Route(path, fn, opts);
   ...
   this.routes.push(route);
 }
```

and later

```js
Router.prototype.findFirstRoute = function (url) {
  var isMatch;
  var routeHandler;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.routes.length; i++) {
    route = this.routes[i];

    // only matches if the url matches AND the
    // current environment matches.
    isMatch = route.handler.test(url, {
      where: Meteor.isServer ? 'server' : 'client'
    });

    if (isMatch)
      return route;
  }

  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no priority. The first route matching the url expression will be returned. The /: parameter is to define a single route with dynamic data context, typically a db index or unique key.